# When Using Excel in OneDrive Can I Hide Some Worksheets From Particular Users?

Tags: permissions, onedrive

I have Office 365. I would like to save an Excel file to One Drive and share it with two associates.
I will call them User 1 and User 2. The spreadsheet contains financial data and I want to limit the access
each user has. More specifically, is it possible to specify that User 1 can only access worksheet "User1Stuff" and User 2 can only access worksheet "User2Stuff"?  BTW -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not possible in Excel, in both desktop and online.

You can protect the worksheet for unwanted modification, as you might already know. Or even go one step ahead and encrypt the content of the whole workbook so that every time you try to open the document it will require a password. But, there are no ways to encrypt each sheet on a workbook with a different password. It's either the whole workbook or none.

Maybe you want to think of creating 2 separate Excel workbooks with specific access for each.